# Wifi working on band 5 but not 2.4

Tags: wireless, authentication, timeout

I have recently installed Ubuntu for the first time ever on an old laptop and it went mostly well. A couple of days ago I dug out another old laptop and installed Ubuntu 16 LTS desktop (32 bit this time). Unfortunately this time connecting to wifi wont work. If I change location I can get in range of the 5 band which I can connect to without any problem. The difference in name between the two is the ' 5' at the end of the name (and the band of course).

I have looked around a bit for this problem but it seems like it is the other way around for everyone else. I also have a range extender for the 2.4 band that I can't connect to either. To rule out some conflict issue I checked that I have the same problem trying to connect to a wifi hotspot on my phone.

All these networks that I can't connect to work without any issue for the other Ubuntu laptop, as well as a windows 10 machine and a few android systems.

System log shows that it is an issue with timouts when trying to authenticate but editing the connections show that the right password is being used. All I get however is the trying to connect animation on the wireless symbol and then a message saying that I am disconnected.

While I am completely new at Linux I have done a bit of searching and tried a couple of things like network manager restart. I have also checked that my hardware is properly supported (it was the very top device listed under Intel).

Does anyone have any clue why one band is working while I can't authenticate on the other?

Comment: Which Wi-Fi chipset do you have?

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 16 doesn't exist. You mean 16.04. The version number represents 2016.April.

Comment: @Android Dev. The hardware is PRO/Wireless 3945 ABG (Golan) from Intel.

Comment: @wjandrea I know it was a bit shorthand, but I was on my mobile in the middle of the night and got a bit uncertain of the exact number. I did not know about how the versions where assigned so thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: Are the problem access points using wireless N mode only?

Comment: @Jeremy31 According to the home page (below) it supports 802.11b/g/n/ac but I have not found any settings for that when logging in to the router and I have had no problem at all on the 5G band which I assume is more likely to utilize the higher speeds. 
I have seen that n can be a problem so I have done the disabling (I think) by running:
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

https://consumer.huawei.com/uk/smart-home/b525/specs/

Edit: The mobile hotspot I have no idea how to control for that, but the spec is:
802.11 a,b g,n,ac, dual-band

Comment: The intel 3945 is not N or AC capable and uses iwlegacy and iwl3945 modules

Comment: @Jeremy31 I'm not sure about how to use this information. Are you suggesting that 2.4G is N or AC only while 5G is not? The only connection I have been able to make is the 5G band on the router which I cannot connect to on the 2.4G band. Surely it would be the other way around if it was a problem with the N-compatibility?

Comment: I can't know how those AP's are set but I can make those changes to make 5ghz b/g/n and 2.4 N only on my AP